# Gson.fromJson format java class

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a json string like so:

```
{
"user-TESTING": [{
    "name": "SERVICE",
    "label": "another test",
    "tags": [],
    "credentials": {
        "PASSWORD": "TestMe",
        "NAME": "http://www.blahblah",
        "USER": "TEST"
    },
    "syslog_url": ""
}]
```

}

How would I format my class so I can use `gson.fromJson(<jsonString>, <class>)` ?

Comment: What class have you tested and what error have you got?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Something
{
    @SerializedName("user-TESTING")
    User[] user;

    static class User
    {
        String name;
        String label
        String[] tags;
        Credentials credentials;
        String syslog_url;
    }

    static class Credentials
    {
        String PASSWORD;
        String NAME;
        String USER;
    }
}
```

I don't know the content of tags, so I guessed String.

Comment: It won't compile due to `User[] user-TESTING;` line. `user-TESTING` is not a valid Java identifier. Field should be renamed and annotated with `@SerializedName("user-TESTING")`

Comment: Good point. I will edit my answer.

Comment: This is what I needed..the array and serialed name was tripping me up..let me give it a try